# Where are the advanced layout techniques for amp-video in amp-story?

Tags: video, amp-html, amp-story

AMP: [Include images & video](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/media/amp_replacements)

Images has a section called "Advanced layout techniques"

What are the advanced layout techniques for videos in amp-story?

Comment: Try asking at their Google forum: [Amp forum - Google](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/webmasters/category$3Aaccelerated-mobile-pages-amp%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false). They seem to reply that site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `layout="responsive"` layout mentioned in the linked document also works in `<amp-story>`.  The only exception is when it is placed in an `<amp-story-grid-layer>` with the attribute `template="fill"`, as this causes the contents of the layer to become full-bleed.